# how $form->error show manually

Tags: cakephp

in my application am showing a popup div form.from that popup form am submitting which controller calls webservice and return the popup automatically closes. Am using ajax->submit for button.I should not close the popup form if an error occur from the controller.

How to do this.Also i need to show the relevant error mesage below the particular input box.How to show the $form->error manually

thanks

Answer (score 1):

here is an answer:

CakePHP 2.x
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#displaying-and-checking-errors

CakePHP 1.3
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#error

Comment: you sent him straight to the manual. I love it. I updated the urls for the 2.x and 1.3 versions of CakePHP